# Where can I find a feed of App Store new releases?

Tags: app-store

Not sure this is the correct forum for this, and if it isn't, my apologies in advance.

Is there a feed of App Store new releases somewhere? Or a feed/list of apps with their category and release date?

This listing is gone from the App Store proper and I'd like to see if it would be possible to make an app to replace it's functionality.

Comment: Unfortunately that's newly released music OR top apps, no newly released apps... :/

Comment: From the iTunes RSS Feed Generator: https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/newapplications/limit=300/xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://itunes.apple.com/us/rss/newapplications/limit=100/xml

You can build your own category-specific feed here: https://rss.itunes.apple.com/us/

PS: Only added this answer because Linuxios' answer leads to a page with an XML error because 300 results doesn't seem allowed. I tried with 200 and it worked so it seems a bit odd.

Comment: In very early days it was 400, then 300 and since years they allow only 200 for RSS.

Comment: Any idea how to get Apple TV or Apple Watch apps? The generator doesn't provide this kind of options.